# Excel: How to separate the content of a cell into 3 different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel question:
I have a sheet where each cell consist of 3 number separated with a 'space'.
How do I separate the numbers in 3 different cells? How do I do that without using Macros and VBA (I have an old Mac version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple in both Excel 2010 and 2013. See the picture. Use the delimited and then check the space. You can also do in 2003 by importing the file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, In **B1** enter:

=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))

and copy across:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the value is a real number (eg with `SPACE` as the digit grouping symbol), or is merely a text string.  If it is a text string, then either of the two previously offered solutions will work.

But if it is a real number, with `SPACE` for the digit grouping symbol, then try these formulas:

```
A1:  Your number  eg: 123 456 789

B1: =MOD($A$1,10^3)
C1: =MOD(INT($A$1/10^3),10^3)
D1: =MOD(INT($A$1/10^6),10^3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you do. How would you spit this for example?
10.7 81 188

Comment: Since that is **NOT** `a real number` you would use one of the other suggestions, as I wrote.